# Ordering rows with id parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table in a MariaDB database with several rows like:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| id | faseID | fase_tipo | fase_nr | tarefa_id |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  5 |      3 |         2 |       1 |         2 |
|  6 |      3 |         2 |       2 |         2 |
| 17 |      3 |         2 |       3 |         2 |
| 12 |      3 |         3 |       1 |         6 |
| 18 |      3 |         3 |       2 |         6 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Generated by:

```
SELECT id, 
       faseID, 
       fase_tipo, 
       fase_nr, 
       tarefa_id 
   FROM tarefas 
   WHERE obra = '15ID000' AND 
         faseID = '3' AND 
         tarefa_id <> '0' AND 
         tarefa_main = '2'
   ORDER BY fase_tipo ASC
```

I'm having trouble ordering this search result, because I want to have the table ordered as:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| id | faseID | fase_tipo | fase_nr | tarefa_id |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  5 |      3 |         2 |       1 |         2 |
|  6 |      3 |         2 |       2 |         2 |
| 12 |      3 |         3 |       1 |         6 |
| 18 |      3 |         3 |       2 |         6 |
| 17 |      3 |         2 |       3 |         2 |
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

What I mean is, use the field `tarefa_id` to make the rows appear after the row with that `id`. And inside that have it ordered with `fase_nr`.

Is there a any to target all the rows with `tarefa_id` to appear after `id` = `tarefa_id`?

Comment: Your example makes no sense.  There are no rows where `id` = `tarefa_id`.

Comment: @gimley, what I need is to have the rows where `tarefa_id` is present in `id` to show after the row with said `id` is printed.

@GordonLinoff, there is a row with `id` = 6 and two rows with `tarefa_id` = 6

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Why does your code say `ORDER BY fase_tipo` if that's not what you want? 2. Why does the  `id=17` not appear after `id=6`? 3. Is there a rule somewhere stating that `id` is always larger than `tarefa_id`?

Comment: @Niklas the `ORDER BY fase_tipo` was just to show the rows ordered by this parameter. The `tarefa_id` points to the `id` of the row that these rows need to appear after. If `tarefa_id` does not appear in the `id` (like this example) them they are ordered using the `id`.

Comment: Please list all columns of your table tarefas with data. You may have a column which may help sorting the ones from your result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below, it should give you what you want by using a self join and the `coalesce` function.

```
    with test_data as (
        select 5 as id, 3 as faseID, 2 as fase_tipo, 1 as fase_nr, 2 as tarefa_id from dual
        union all
        select 6 as id, 3 as faseID, 2 as fase_tipo, 2 as fase_nr, 2 as tarefa_id from dual
        union all
        select 12 as id, 3 as faseID, 3 as fase_tipo, 1 as fase_nr, 6 as tarefa_id from dual
        union all
        select 18 as id, 3 as faseID, 3 as fase_tipo, 2 as fase_nr, 6 as tarefa_id from dual
        union all
        select 17 as id, 3 as faseID, 2 as fase_tipo, 3 as fase_nr, 2 as tarefa_id from dual
    )
    -- This is the core you should pay attention to
    select td1.* 
    from test_data td1
    left join test_data td2 
    on td2.id = td1.tarefa_id
    order by coalesce(td2.id, td1.id), td1.id, td1.fase_nr
    --
;
```

Granted, I did this in Oracle, but the general idea should apply.

Output:

```
ID|FASEID|FASE_TIPO|FASE_NR|TAREFA_ID
--+------+---------+-------+---------
 5|     3|        2|      1|        2
 6|     3|        2|      2|        2
12|     3|        3|      1|        6
18|     3|        3|      2|        6
17|     3|        2|      3|        2
```

If your columns are not of a numeric type you will need to convert them in the `order by` clause for sorting:

```
with test_data as (
    select '12' as id, '3' as faseID, '3' as fase_tipo, '1' as fase_nr, '6' as tarefa_id from dual
    union all
    select '5' as id, '3' as faseID, '2' as fase_tipo, '1' as fase_nr, '2' as tarefa_id from dual
    union all
    select '18' as id, '3' as faseID, '3' as fase_tipo, '2' as fase_nr, '6' as tarefa_id from dual
    union all
    select '6' as id, '3' as faseID, '2' as fase_tipo, '2' as fase_nr, '2' as tarefa_id from dual
    union all
    select '17' as id, '3' as faseID, '2' as fase_tipo, '3' as fase_nr, '2' as tarefa_id from dual
)
-- This is the core you should pay attention to
select td1.* 
from test_data td1
left join test_data td2 
on td2.id = td1.tarefa_id
order by to_number(coalesce(td2.id, td1.id)), to_number(td1.id), to_number(td1.fase_nr)
--
;
```

Comment: I was thinking about the left join as well. This still gives me a wrong order.

Comment: I get the exact order you specified in your question when I execute the above.

Comment: I've adapted your core to this:

`select td1.id,
td1.faseID, td1.fase_tipo, td1.fase_nr, td1.tarefa_id from tarefas td1 left join tarefas td2 on td2.id = td1.tarefa_id where td1.obra = '15ID000' AND td1.faseID = '3' AND td1.tarefa_id <> '0' AND td1.tarefa_main = '2' order by coalesce(td2.id, td1.id), td1.id, td1.fase_nr; `

And I got the same as the first table.

Comment: Now, I see you are using single quotes, are these fields actually `varchar` or otherwise non-numeric? If that is the case, I will add to my answer above, you need to convert your columns to numeric value for sorting in the `order by` clause.

Comment: `obra` is `varchar`, the others are `int`'s. I'll remove the single quotes

Comment: Just to be certain, ensure that in the `order by` all of the items are numeric.

Comment: I've got it working, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.